# Why did we set cart props value to empty array? React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I am following a tutorial. He said we should set cart to empty array in props. As we are checking `cart.length===0`. And we will get a big fat error, if we do not add it. But I am not getting any error even if I remove it. I want to know when can I get an error and why would it happen? My cart is getting array of objects from a local file.

**Cart Container**

```
// why passing cart = [] instead of cart only
const CartContainer = ({ cart=[], total, dispatch }) => {
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return (
      <section className="cart">
        {/* cart header */}
        <header>
          <h2>your bag</h2>
          <h4 className="empty-cart">is currently empty</h4>
        </header>
      </section>
    );
  }
  return (
    <section className="cart">
      {/* cart header */}
      <header>
        <h2>your bag</h2>
      </header>
      {/* cart items */}
      <article>
        {cart.map((item) => {
          return <CartItem key={item.id} {...item} />;
        })}
      </article>
      {/* cart footer */}
      <footer>
        <hr />
        <div className="cart-total">
          <h4>
            total <span>${total}</span>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <button
          className="btn clear-btn"
          onClick={() => dispatch({ type: CLEAR })}
        >
          clear cart
        </button>
      </footer>
    </section>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  //   return { amount: state.amount };
  const { total, cart } = store;
  return { cart, total };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CartContainer);
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const initialState = {
      cart: cart,
      total:3,
      amount:7,
  };

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

**Reducer**

```
export default function reducer(state, action) {

    if (action.type === CLEAR) {
        return {
            ...state, cart: []
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have set an empty array here is because you are expecting the cart to be an array and in case if it is undefined or null it will throw an error. You are not getting an error here is because you have `cart = []` in props.

```
// why passing cart = [] instead of cart only
const CartContainer = ({ cart=[], total, dispatch }) => {
```

Here you are passing `cart = []`. This means if if the value of cart is `undefined` or `null` then this will take the empty `[]` as a default value of that prop.

Hence, When you are trying to access `cart.length` it doesn't throw any error as it is initialized as an empty array `[]` in params. You will get an error if you do something like this.

```
const CartContainer = ({ cart, total, dispatch }) => {
if (cart.length === 0) {
    return (
      <section className="cart">
        {/* cart header */}
        <header>
          <h2>your bag</h2>
          <h4 className="empty-cart">is currently empty</h4>
        </header>
      </section>
    );
  }
....
```

You can handle the error as

```
...

if (cart?.length === 0) { // In case if optional chaining is not set then try if(cart && cart.length === 0)
    return (
      <section className="cart">
        {/* cart header */}
        <header>
          <h2>your bag</h2>
          <h4 className="empty-cart">is currently empty</h4>
        </header>
      </section>
    );
  }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

cart.length WILL throw an error if you're using javascript, it's just, it will throw an error during program runtime that

`you can not read property length of undefined`

Using typescript you could do

`cart?.length`

And it would work perfectly fine. To prevent case no.1 you have to assign empty array as default value, so when no props are passes, you indeed have empty array with length of 0 instead of undefined